# SignaturePad not initialising in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm using signaturePad with ie8 but it's not initialising on the page, it only appears after typing

```
  $('.sigPad').signaturePad({drawOnly:true,validateFields:false})
```

into the console, (though I already have this in my js file)
then it appears like;
[image]

then I need to click on 'Draw it' to be able to use it, i.e after clicking it appears as;
[image]

How do I get this to work without having to manually call the signaturePad function?

Comment: Is the `.signaturePad()` function inside a `$(document).ready()` or `$(function() {})` event?

Comment: inside $(document).ready()

Comment: Also note, SignaturePad relies on the HTML5 canvas tag, which IE8 does not natively support.  There are numerous issues with using IE8, e.g., https://github.com/thread-pond/signature-pad/issues/75